# Access a specific index from an arrary ojbect during mapfunction

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, nested, tailwind-css

So I am trying to access set a img tag's src to a specific url from a firestore collection. I am able to great a gallery of all of the images, howver I would like to set a specific image to a div as I would like to create a carosel eventually.

This is my current code which works when I want to access all of the images.

```
{notes.map(({id, data}) => 
  <img className=' h-48 w-48 object-cover hover:opacity-80'
       key={id}
       src={data.imageUrl}
       alt='imgs'
       >
 </img>
)}
```

The object and array look as follows

```
0: data: {
         createdAt: timestamp0
         imageUrl: URL0
         }
   id: "1eL90ZbzYsLRiKgOzcJx"
1: data: {
         createdAt: timestamp1
         imageUrl: URL1
         }
   id: ""1eL90ZbzYsLRiKgOzcJx""
```

I have tried to use an index, but I always get an error:

```
{notes.map(({id, data}) => 
  <img className=' h-48 w-48 object-cover hover:opacity-80'
       key={id}
       src={data[1].imageUrl}
       alt='imgs'
       >
 </img>
)}
```

Ive tried as many youtube videos and other questions here, but can't seem to get it to work! Any help would be great

Comment: your question is not clear. what do you want? when you are looping through all the notes and specifying image url, then it is working as you said, now what you want with image , do you need to show one image in all notes?

Comment: Hey sorry about the confusion, essentially I wanted to create a <img></img> where the src was a url from the array. However, I jist figured out that mapping was too much and I should have just done this: ```<img className='h-full w-full'
             src={notes[0].data.imageUrl}></img>``` and it works

Answer (score 0):

So it was a waste of time using a map function. Instead I could just do this

```
<img className='h-full w-full'
     src={notes[0].data.imageUrl}>
</img>
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).